# Scifi movie from 70s, 80s or 90s – A scientist measuring intelligence

Tags: story-identification, movie

I don't remember much about this movie. Only one quote. The problem is, I only remember it translated into Serbian while I think the original was in English. At first I thought the movie was Suburban Commando but I didn't find the scene with the quote.

The movie is from 70s,80s or 90s. There is a scientist experimenting with measuring intelligence with a machine. He attaches his machine to plants (including what is implied to be Ficus Benjamina) and appliances. The machine looks like EEG machine somewhat.

He attaches it to other character (he might be strongman type/bodybuilder). Once he reads his intelligence, he tells him the quote.

> "Your intelligence is somewhere between ficus and toaster."
>
> "Tvoja inteligencija je negde izmedju fikusa i tostera."

Or maybe the character asks him what the result of the measurement is and the answer they get is

> "Somewhere between ficus and toaster."

or maybe

> "In the middle between ficus and the toaster."

That's all I remember.

Comment: Anyone wanna tell me what a ficus is?

Comment: @DannyMcG It's a fig tree.

Comment: @DannyMcG If you have one as a houseplant it might be referred to as a "benjamina" (Ficus benjamina, a.k.a. weeping fig).

Comment: Ficus Benjamina is what the quote is about.

It might be other plant in the original movie. But it was translated as ficus in Serbian.

Comment: He wouldn't have been [intending to measure the intelligence of various lawyers](https://archive.org/details/AmazingStoriesVolume01Number03/page/n92/mode/1up) (in order to rule cases in favor of the person with the worse lawyer), would he?

Comment: @JacobC.saysReinstateMonica Nah. It is a movie. A small scene in a movie. I think it might be an action movie.

Comment: This sounds as something out of a Red Dwarf episode. Might it be an episode in a TV series instead of a movie?

Comment: Might be. I thought maybe Alf or something like that, but I don't remember. Does anybody remember scene from one of Police Academy movies like that?

Comment: @jo1storm Your mention of Police Academy reminded me of the Naked Gun movies/  Police Squad! show.  Ed Williams plays a scientist/inventor who makes some whacky stuff, but I couldn't find anything like the scene you described in my brief look through the synopsis of the episodes/my recollection of the movies. But perhaps someone who remembers it better could chime in.

Comment: Maybe "Honey, I shrunk the kids", or one of the sequels? Or a tv show made with the same name? Hm...

Comment: Don't you remember some features of the scientist, like color of hair, clothes, body shape, beard, glasses or something? Did he have any affiliated people around him in the movie? A wife, children or assistants? Did he have some kind of vehicle to drive around? A car? Which color? Was it purely with actors or were there any special effects or people in costumes?

Comment: Did the machine make sounds? Are you 100% positive that it was "ficus" and "toaster" or could it be another word for the plant and any other kitchen tool? What was the reaction of the strongman when hearing the result? Do you remember any of the actors or maybe did you see any of them in other movies?

Comment: I don't remember any of the actors. Might be other plant, the toaster I am sure. He laughed or had neutral reaction, because he was friends with the scientist, I think.

Comment: Could this be "Max Headroom: 20 minutes into the future"?  It sounds the kind of quote that Max would make, but I can't find scripts to search through....

Comment: I checked it out, but it is not it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, I somehow missed this question! I believe you're looking for the Tommy Chong comedy [Far Out Man](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099546/) from 1990. There's a scene where **a doctor tests his brainwaves and says his intelligence is somewhere between plankton and a toaster**. He then suggests he goes into politics or something, yuk yuk. Tommy's not a strongman, though, more of a stoned hippie. (And BTW, *his ex wife is called Tree*, and they discuss her a minute earlier.) You can actually see the scene in the trailer at 0:25:

Comment: Thank you, that's the one. Pretty buff hippy, though. Look at the size of those pecs!

Answer (score 1):

I see this question keeps popping up but nobody seems able to find an answer so I've thought I'll take my chance with a wild guess: could it be **The Man With The Screaming Brain** with Bruce Campbell?

The sentence you cite sounds like an insult one of his cocky characters would say; which, together with the brain-related subject, had me immediately think this might be the movie you're looking for.

Wikipedia has a [detailed summary of the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_with_the_Screaming_Brain).

Comment: It is not that. This was older sort of movie.